# Struggle to choose a model (glm, glm with qualitative variable, glmm)

Tags: generalized-linear-model, residuals, glmm

I'm currently trying to fit a model on some data, but I am quite struggling.

**Data**

- There are 20000 entries in the dataset. One entry is a random pick of bacteria (among a set of ~200 bacteria).
- The response variable is the total number of chemical reactions found in all the genomes of these bacteria
- There are three independent variables:

  - X1 (quantitative, continuous) : the average genetic distance between all the bacteria
  - X2 (quantitative, discrete) : the average genome size between all the bacteria
  - X3 (quantitative, discrete) : the number of bacteria

*nb* : since their magnitude is really different, all the variable are scaled.

**Issue**

The variable X3 is the one I'm struggling with. It has a clear effect (visible on the figure below), but creates a bias in the residuals. It actually only has a reduced set of possible values (from 2 to 20), meaning many of the entries has the same values. (see plot).

*n.b. (2)* : the higher X3, the lesser the variance in the data, because when the number of bacteria increases, we got closer to the full population (every data become more and more similar).

**EDIT** : I think another problem might be the fact that at small values of X3, the relation between Y and X1 is polynomial, a tendancy which disapear when X3 increases.

[image]

I tried with a quasipoisson GLM (not Poisson because the response data is overdispersed), which gives an R2 of 0.84. The residuals~fitted (biased) is on the figure below (results are similar with a negative-binomial glm).

[image]

**Attempts to solve the issue**

I thought about several solutions:

- Treat X3 as a factor, which solves the bias in the residuals, but adds many parameters, with a very strong effect compared to the effects of X1 and X2.
- Treat X3 as a random effect in a mixed model, which also solves the bias, but I have doubts on the "validity" of this solution, particularly because the r squared jumps from 0.09 with fixed effects only to 0.98 with the random effect, and because (as far as I know), mixed models are more designed for data with "hierarchical" sampling ( I don't remember how to say this in english...), like students/classroom/school or sampling site/region/bigger region
- Build "sub-models", i.e. one model for each X3 level (not a big fan of this one ...)

Any suggestions ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried interacting X3 with other variables? That should at the minimum approximate the "sub-models" approach

Comment: Not yet, this is the next attempt I planned

Comment: You could also try exploring the possible presence of non-linearities through LIME/shap and similar methods on the predictions of some quick machine learning appraoch, like a random forest / xgboost or similar. These sometimes approximate nonlinearities quite well and can give insights into the data, on how to form the final model.

Comment: @runr Interactions terms do not solve the problem. I can give a try to LIME and others, but I don't know how these work....